# Show the upload button 1 by 1 ,paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Right now,im using paperclip to upload multiple picture, however ,in the view ,its look not nice that it do have 5 button of upload(i set it allow 5 times of upload). In this case,i would like to try that, initially it just show 1 button for upload and if the button have file ,it will just continues to show the second button until the fifth button.

another problem is,when i edit and delete all my picture, it dont show the upload button edy.
I guess this have to provide a logic solution to solve this. I got a thought that i need to use counter and boolean condition to set it whether it show or not. However,in the view,i do not know how it can be done. Anyone can give some hints to let me proceed?

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :assets do |asset_fields| %>
        <p>

        <% if asset_fields.object.new_record? %>
                <%= asset_fields.file_field :asset %>
        <% end %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different views for new and edit action, or different partials for upload fields.

Comment: thanks for the reply,but whats the condition that detect a user clicked the first upload button? .new_record?